# Call function from method in one classes in another class

Tags: c#, class, methods

Hello so i got very easy function to download files from FTP. Looks like this:

```
//Download files from FTP, return true of false if succed
        public static bool DownloadFileFromFTP( string ip, string RemoteFilePath, string LocalFilePath, string username, string password)
        {
            try
            {
                FtpClient client = new FtpClient(ip);
                client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
                client.Connect();

                ProgressBar progressBar;
                progressBar = new ProgressBar();
                Progress<double> progress = new Progress<double>(x => {
                    if (x > 0)
                    {
                        progressBar.Report((double)x / 100);
                    }
                });

                bool succes = client.DownloadFile(LocalFilePath, RemoteFilePath, FtpLocalExists.Overwrite, FluentFTP.FtpVerify.Retry, progress);
                if(succes == true)
                {
                    succes = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    succes = false;
                }
                client.Disconnect();
                progressBar.Dispose();
                return succes;

            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
                return false;
            }

        }
```

And this method is in one class and i call it in another class like this:

```
Functions_General.DownloadFileFromFTP("192.168.240.86", "Ultra_Script/path", @"C:\Windows\Temp\Adobe_Reader.exe", "username", "password");
```

Everything works as  expected. But the function itself have progressbar inside it and its disposing after finished downloading with this:

```
progressBar.Dispose();
```

But there comes the problem i need to dispose it in class where im calling the method is there any option how can i achieve that?

I need to have 3 synchronous progress bars and dispose them after all of 3 downloads are complete.

Thanks,

Comment: Perhaps you should let the caller of your method take care of creating the progress bar, and have them pass in an instance of `Progress` which your method then just passes to `client.DownloadFile`?

Comment: that was one idea i got but when i have like 5 calls of this there i found useless to have there 5 same instances of progress so im asking if there isnt better solution :D

Comment: I don't understand what the issue is, then - why would the caller need to dispose of something that they don't create?

Comment: FYI, this code is pointless: `if(succes == true)
                {
                    succes = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    succes = false;
                }`

Comment: Also, generally disposable objects should be created in a `using` block, which handles any closing/disposing of the object at the end of the block (no explicit call to `Dispose` is required). Your code could be: `using (var client = new FtpClient(ip)) { client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password); client.Connect(); using (var progressBar = new ProgressBar()) { var progress = new Progress<double>(x => { if (x > 0) { progressBar.Report(x / 100); } }); return client.DownloadFile(LocalFilePath, RemoteFilePath, FtpLocalExists.Overwrite, FluentFTP.FtpVerify.Retry, progress); } }`